# How to set all subusers created by a user, or their role, to expire on a specific date

Tags: rules, ubercart, users, entities

I need to create licensing functionality for a website. Part is done: via the subuser module, I can set up a licensing admin who can create a certain number of subusers that function as licenses based on role perms. So far so good. The admin's role can be set to expire through ubercart.

Here's the difficulty. I need the subusers to either lose their role or be deleted when the licensing admin's role ends. I had thought the Role Expire module (www.drupal.org/project/role_expire) would solve this problem, but it sets expiration based on duration, and I need all the subusers to expire on one specific date, no matter when they were created.

I've considered Rules, along with possibly setting a field on the licensing admin, using a view, somehow using the relation created by the subuser module, but I don't see how to get that to work.

Comment: Rules or a custom module would be your best bet.  However it doesn't look like Subuser currently has any Rules integration, so a custom module might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Subuser integrates with Relation, and Relation integrates with Rules.  Anyone have suggestions about how to use that connection?